# parse a string with brackets to arguments

Tags: python, list, parsing, split

I need to parse some strings into function variable lists.

I can have a simple string, such as `vars = '3,5,1'`

I parse it using `args = [int(arg) if arg.isdigit() else arg for arg in vars.split(',')]`

However I might get a string such as `vars = [1, 2, 5, 4], 1, 5`

And I want my result to be `[[1,2,5,4],1,5]`

How can I modify my parsing to support this case?

Comment: You can try using [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in `ast` module:

```
import ast
result = ast.literal_eval(f'[{vars}]')
```

This will treat `vars` as an ordinary list literal.

Answer (score 1):

```
import ast
print(list(ast.literal_eval(vars)))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.